# How to detect the ip address of the device itself?

Tags: 8, users

Using PHP and Drupal 8, I am trying to detect the ip address of the device itself and not the ip address of the router where the device is connected through the internet.

```
$DeviceIP = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
```

the above will return the ip address of the router where the device is connected, but what I am really trying to get is the unique ip address of the device hardware.

So say I have two mobile phones (Mobile A & Mobile B) connected to the same WiFi network, if I ran the above code on both mobiles, both will return the same IP Address...
However, I am expecting Mobile A to return an IP Address which is unique and DIFFERENT from the one returned by Mobile B.

In General, what I am trying to achieve is the ability to know **if a registered user on my site is using more than one device to login to his account.**

**Update 1:**

I am not really interested to get the ip address of the mobile hardware but more interested in a method to distinguish between two different mobiles used by the same user to access his own account on my site...

Getting the Device Name or Device Serial Number or whatever information which will be unique for the device will get the job done.

How do you think this could be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
// Get all information available about the active device from the "HTTP request headers".
$currentdevicedata = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

I know this is not the best approach to follow but at least for now it can do the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. User routers mask IPs, see the definition of the NAT protocol that most home routers use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

You could try to do something based on HTTP Headers (User-Agent), using cookies or the session itself, but none of them will be really reliable.

Comment: @Clive I am not really interested to get the **ip address** of the mobile hardware but more interested in a method to distinguish between two different mobiles used by the same user to access his own account on my site... How do you think this could be done ?

Comment: As penyaskito mentioned, it won't be reliable (it's not designed to be; if anything the privacy trends of the last decade have made it harder to track users). But you can integrate something like the [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) library to make a best guess

Comment: Seconding Clive's comments. What you are looking for isn't exactly doable.